# Deleting Row from Grid view without using Database

Tags: c#

I am using this code to delete rows from grid view and the rows are getting deleted but when I add a new row to my Grid view the deleted row comes back again any suggestions what should I do to delete row from my grid view and I am not using database on it. Thanks in Advance.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpId", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DeptName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpAddress", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpSalary", typeof(string)));
        string Id = string.Empty;
        string Name = string.Empty;
        string DeptName = string.Empty;
        string EmpAddress = string.Empty;
        string EmpSalary = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[i];
            if (i != e.RowIndex)
            {
                Id = row.Cells[1].Text;
                Name = row.Cells[2].Text;
                DeptName = row.Cells[3].Text;
                EmpAddress = row.Cells[4].Text;
                EmpSalary = row.Cells[5].Text;
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["EmpId"] = Id;
                dr["EmpName"] = Name;
                dr["DeptName"] = DeptName;
                dr["EmpAddress"] = EmpAddress;
                dr["EmpSalary"] = EmpSalary;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

        }

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

My add to row code is this

```
private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
    {
        // check view state is not null   
        if (ViewState["EmployeeDetails"] != null)
        {
            //get datatable from view state   
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["EmployeeDetails"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //add each row into data table   
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["EmpId"] = txtEmpId.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["EmpName"] = txtEmpName.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["DeptName"] = txtDeptName.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["EmpAddress"] = txtEmpAddress.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["EmpSalary"] = txtEmpSalary.Text;
                }
                //Remove initial blank row   
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                }
                //add created Rows into dataTable   
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Bind Gridview with latest Row   
                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: the error is somewhere in the `AddRow` method which isn't shown - I assume you bind the data from your database again in that method (where the data wasn't deleted)

Comment: @fubo I have posted my add row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you load the employees after adding from your ViewState

```
DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["EmployeeDetails"];
```

the deleted row wasn't deleted there. I would suggest to edit the `DataTable` in your `ViewState`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["EmployeeDetails"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["EmployeeDetails"];
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        ViewState["EmployeeDetails"] = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
    }
}
```

and

```
private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
{  
    if (ViewState["EmployeeDetails"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["EmployeeDetails"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
        drCurrentRow["EmpId"] = txtEmpId.Text;
        drCurrentRow["EmpName"] = txtEmpName.Text;
        drCurrentRow["DeptName"] = txtDeptName.Text;
        drCurrentRow["EmpAddress"] = txtEmpAddress.Text;
        drCurrentRow["EmpSalary"] = txtEmpSalary.Text;

        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["EmployeeDetails"] = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```